# How to give route of another solution in NServiceBus routing?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0, nservicebus

I am implementing NServiceBus in .net core 2.2 application. Everything is working fine but now I have decided to move handlers in a separate solution and call them from the webapi solution. Initially I had everything setup in a same solution so I could implement the routing like this:

```
var endpointConfiguration = newEndpointConfiguration(AssemblyName);
    var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<LearningTransport>();
    endpointConfiguration.SendOnly();

    var routing = transport.Routing();
    routing.RouteToEndpoint(
            assembly: typeof(OrderProcessEvent).Assembly,
            destination: "Orders");

    endpoint = NServiceBus.Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Now how can I provide path of other solution in "destination"? Something like:

```
 routing.RouteToEndpoint(
        assembly: typeof(OrderProcessEvent).Assembly,
        destination: @"C:\Endpoints\Orders");
```

Update:

By Daniels's answer. I have tried this:

```
var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration(AssemblyName);
                var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<LearningTransport>();
                //endpointConfiguration.SendOnly();
                transport.StorageDirectory(@"..\.Endpoints\");
                var routing = transport.Routing();
                routing.RouteToEndpoint(
                    assembly: typeof(OrderProcessEvent).Assembly,
                    destination: "Orders");

                endpoint = NServiceBus.Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

But I am still getting the same error

> "No destination specified for message: Namespace.Orders"

Answer (score 2):

When using the learning transport (caveat not a production transport) you can specify the storage directory with

```
var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<LearningTransport>();
transport.StorageDirectory("PathToStoreTransportFiles");
```

if all the endpoints point to that same directory they can communicate together. A quick example, let's say your `src` directory is structured the following way

```
src\
  Solution1\
  Solution2\
```

you could configure the learning transport like the following

```
var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<LearningTransport>();
transport.StorageDirectory("..\.learningtransport");
```

which then creates

```
src\
  Solution1\
  Solution2\
  .learningtransport
```

please be aware if you set the storage directory like this you might need to take into account that endpoints will be executed under `bin\[Release|Debug]\netXYZ`.

More information about the learning transport configuration can be found in https://docs.particular.net/transports/learning

Comment: Daniel's solution will definitely work, but since the Learning Transport is really designed to be used just within a single solution, the point at which you graduate to multiple solutions is probably the point where you should select your real, production-ready transport and start using that. We have guidance to help with that now: https://docs.particular.net/transports/selecting

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried your solution but still getting the same error. Can you see update part in the question?

Comment: Is it possible to upload a repro or your solution to github then I can send a PR to fix it :) ?

Comment: Could it be that the Orders message is not marked as a message? Do you use conventions or the IEvent, ICommand and IMessage interfaces? If you use conventions the convention has to map that type correctly or the Orders message has to implement ICommand or IMessage if the type is sent

Comment: Now, the error has gone but it's still not calling the handler (which is a different solution) and just returning "Ok();" this is how I am calling it "await _messageSession.Send(message).ConfiureAwait(false);" and in the other solution I have an order command like "public class Order : ICommand" 
I have a debugger attached in my order handler but its not getting hit? Any idea why? The routing configuration can be seen in the update part of my original question

Comment: Please send me an email to daniel dot marbach at particular dot net with more details or a link to a repro or attach your solution zipped and I'll point out what is missing